# CSS: Equal height divs without margin hack

Tags: css, html, center

Can you make two divs have equal height without

1) margin hacks because then I can't have a border :

```
margin-bottom : -500px;
padding-bottom : 500px;
```

2) Javascript because then there is flicker on the page for non-cached users.

3) Fixed height because then I can't add more content dynamically.

It is for this page http://www.stdicon.com/ for the two divs in the middle (which are currently sized in JS, but I'd prefer a pure CSS solution)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't care about liquidity/zooming, take a 1 pixel high horizontal screenshot of the top most of the pink and light orange, and make it a vertically repeating background that's behind the two divisions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the Faux Columns approach can solve your problem:

[Faux Columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/)

Answer (score 0):

Use absolutely positioned divs nested in a relatively positioned wrapper to create equal height columns using the following steps:

- Create the columns using inline-block
- Create a wrapper div around all the columns and set it to be relatively positioned
- Place an absolutely positioned div as the last element inside the wrapper div
- Set the absolutely positioned div to { bottom:0; height: 100%; z-index: -1; }
- Set the width of the absolutely positioned div equal to the width of the first column
- Set the left offset of the absolutely positioned div so that it overlaps the first column
- Set the desired border and background color of the absolutely positioned div
- Repeat this step for the remaining columns if necessary

Here is an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Equal Height Columns</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
  /* Wrapper */
  .wrapper { position: relative; }
  /* Column */
  .column { display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; }
  /* Layered Illusion */
  .equalizer { position: absolute; bottom:0; left: 0; height: 100%; z-index: -1; }
  /* Border for Column and Illusion */
  .equalizer, .column { border: 1px solid red; border-width: 0 1px; width: 200px; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="first" class="column">
      <span>hello</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div>
        <p>hi</p>
        <p>there</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <span>there</span>
    </div>

    <div class="equalizer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```